# How to handle late arrival records while deduplication in Spark structured streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have just started my journey with Spark Streaming where I am reading data from a Kafka queue using Spark structured streaming. I need to do deduplication in each micro-batch based on key columns(product and org) and order by timestamp field (booked_at).

Deduplicator function will create a micro-batch from streaming dataframe at every 2 seconds. Deduplicated dataframe will be returned to another function for further processing and finally persisted in a DynamoDb. My code works fine except when there are late arriving records in Kafka. For example consider below 4 events in Kafka where first two belongs to first micro-batch after starting streaming job and last two belongs to second micro-batch

```
{"product":"p1","org":"US","quantity":1,"booked_at":"2020-02-05T00:00:05"}
{"product":"p1","org":"US","quantity":2,"booked_at":"2020-02-05T00:00:06"}
{"product":"p1","org":"US","quantity":3,"booked_at":"2020-02-05T00:00:01"}
{"product":"p1","org":"US","quantity":4,"booked_at":"2020-02-05T00:00:03"}
```

Current output of my deduplicator function for each batch is as below

```
+-------+---+--------+-------------------+
|product|org|quantity|          booked_at|
+-------+---+--------+-------------------+
| p1    | US|       3|2020-02-05 00:00:06|
+-------+---+--------+-------------------+

+-------+---+--------+-------------------+
|product|org|quantity|          booked_at|
+-------+---+--------+-------------------+
| p1    | US|       2|2020-02-05 00:00:03|
+-------+---+--------+-------------------+
```

I can safely assume that my late arriving records will not be more than 60 seconds in Kafka and considering this assumption I want my function to somehow consider last 60 seconds of events to do deduplication. So if micro-batch2 records lies within 60 seconds window then output should be below -

```
+-------+---+--------+-------------------+
|product|org|quantity|          booked_at|
+-------+---+--------+-------------------+
| p1    | US|       3|2020-02-05 00:00:06|
+-------+---+--------+-------------------+

+-------+---+--------+-------------------+
|product|org|quantity|          booked_at|
+-------+---+--------+-------------------+
| p1    | US|       3|2020-02-05 00:00:06|
+-------+---+--------+-------------------+
```

Some solutions that I am able to think of -

1. Take 60 seconds worth of data every 2 seconds. Currently it is
   set to consider only last 2 seconds data in every 2 seconds. But this is perhaps not possible as read from Kafka will be based on offsets instead of kafka timestamp.
2. Persist last 60 seconds of data into a cached dataframe and use it while deduplicating micro-batch having 2 seconds of data. This way, I will return only 2 seconds worth of data to next function which will do actual processing.
3. Leave the deduplicator function as it is right now and have another function it end which will compare the processed record timestamp with what is there in DynamoDB and will only write if the last processed record's timestamp is greater than existing one in Dynamo

Is there any other way by which I can handle it better?

Existing code :

```
    def get_deduplicated_dataframe(inputDf: DataFrame, grpKeys: List[String], orderByKey: String) 
  : DataFrame = {
    val outputDf = inputDf.withColumn("rowNumber",row_number()
      .over(Window.partitionBy(grpKeys.head, grpKeys.tail: _*)
        .orderBy(col(orderByKey).desc))).filter("rowNumber = 1").drop("rowNumber")
    outputDf.collect()
    outputDf.cache()
    outputDf
  }

val df = spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("subscribe", "test1")
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
  .load()


  val schema = new StructType()
    .add("product",StringType)
    .add("org",StringType)
    .add("quantity", IntegerType)
    .add("booked_at",TimestampType)

  val payload_df = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as payload")
    .select(from_json(col("payload"), schema).as("data"))
    .select("data.*")

  val query = payload_df.writeStream
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(2000L))
    .foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>

      val groupKeys = List("product", "org")
      val orderByKey = "booked_at"
      val outputDf = get_deduplicated_dataframe(batchDF, groupKeys, orderByKey)
      outputDf.show()
    }.start()


  query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Spark has some built-in support for dedupe in recent versions: look at `withWatermark` and `dropDuplicates`.  But I personally think that dedupe is something better handled in e.g. an akka service.

Comment: Remember that if you want zero possibility of dupes within 60 seconds, you can't have latency less than 60 seconds plus whatever batch interval you have.